# how to go to a commit from history of commits in git?

Tags: git, git-commit

I deleted one file after my first commit, and I want to know how can I revert back to that commit state (all files  in working dir to that state).
Can someone please help me with this?

```
$ git log
commit 2e8bd07a1f7446d2acef86f854ad57dabe4e5834
Author: Sam <sam@mysite.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 21 00:21:12 2016 +030

    baseline

g@DESKTOP MINGW64 /c/mydir (master)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I didn't understand a thing from that post, way too complicated for a newbie like me! Please give me a simple answer

Comment: Try `git checkout .`.

Comment: thanks ! it did the job!

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
$ git log
```

and then checkout the commit :

```
$ git checkout 2e8bd07a1f7446d2acef86f854ad57dabe4e5834
```

Comment: already tried that! it does not work! -> does not bring back the files to working dir!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git checkout FILE` to revert a file in the working directory back to its committed state. This also works for whole directories, so `git checkout .` will recursively revert all files in the current directory.

Comment: Prefer `git checkout -- FILE`, to avoid ambiguities with branch names.